# Ruby on Rails - undefined method - Model can't be accessed by Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller, cloud9-ide

SOLVED - I've added an if statement in the HTML.erb before displaying the profile avatar and it's now appearing. Thank you Mark and Holger for your help.

I'm trying to make my users appear in a league table but I'm getting an error message saying there is an undefined method in my LeaguesController file. I've tried the following class names for my Controller file - LeaguesController < Application Controller and LeaguesController < UsersController (I know the method has been defined in this class, will post both below). 'index' matches the html.erb file name.

LeaguesController (I've tried User.includes(:profile).order(etc) but still doesn't pick up the user fields)

```
class LeaguesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @LMSusers = User.order('last_sign_in_at DESC')
    @MVPusers = User.order('sign_in_count DESC')
    @LMSuser_position = User.order('last_sign_in_at DESC').find_index(current_user)
    @MVPuser_position = User.order('sign_in_count DESC').find_index(current_user)
  end
end
```

User Model file

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Association - Ruby Documentation       
  belongs_to :plan
  has_one :profile
end
```

UsersController

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!


  def index
    @users = User.includes(:profile)
  end

    # Use rails routes in console to find what URL path should be used and 
    # what dynamic ids need to be included. Use params in relevant controller file
    # to include the paramater.

  # GET to /users/:id
  def show 
    # "User" is refering to model with same name -> user.rb
    @user = User.find( params[:id] )
  end

end
```

What's really strange is this code used to work fine. I've compared it to the previous commits before it stopped working and they seem to match up perfectly. When I cloned the commit, that also worked fine so I really don't know where to start looking for this error. I don't have a model file for Leagues but I never have done and it used to work fine. I've never included Leagues in any belongs_to/has_many associations but again, it used to work fine...

Here is the routes file too.

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root to: 'pages#home'
    devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }
    resources :users do
        # Singular resource and profile because requiring only one resource and profile per user
       resource :profile
    end
    resources :leagues
    get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
    resources :contacts, only: :create
    get 'contact-us', to: 'contacts#new', as: 'new_contact'

    # Nested Resources Documentation

end
```

HTML.erb file

```
<div>
  <h1 class="text-center">The Leaderboard</h1></br>
  <p class="text-center">Check how you compare to the top 5 in the community.</p></br>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div>
        <table class="table">
          <tr>
            <th class="league-header" colspan="6">Last Man Standing</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row-header">
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th class="left-column">Job Title</th>
            <th class="left-column">Last Logged In</th>
          </tr>
          <% @LMSusers.each_with_index do |user, index| %>
            <% if index < 5 %>
              <tr class="tr">
                <td style="padding-top: 20px;"><%= index+1 %></td>
                <td class="left-column"><%= link_to user do %><%= image_tag user.profile.avatar.url, class: 'sml-avatar-show-img' %><% end %> <%= link_to user do %><%= user.profile.first_name %> <%= user.profile.last_name %><% end %></td>
                <td style="padding-top: 20px;" class="left-column"><%= user.profile.job_title %></td>
                <td style="padding-top: 20px;" class="left-column"><%= user.last_sign_in_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %></td>
              </tr>
            <% end %>  
          <% end %>
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <% if current_user.profile %>
              <tr class="tr user-tr">
                <td style="padding-top: 20px;" ><%= @LMSuser_position + 1 %></td>
                <td class="left-column"><%= link_to user_path(current_user.id) do %><%= image_tag current_user.profile.avatar.url, class: 'sml-avatar-show-img' %><% end %> <%= link_to user_path(current_user.id) do %><%= current_user.profile.first_name %> <%= current_user.profile.last_name %><% end %></td>
                <td style="padding-top: 20px;" class="left-column"><%= current_user.profile.job_title %></td>
                <td style="padding-top: 20px;" class="left-column"><%= current_user.last_sign_in_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %></td>
              </tr>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div>
        <table class="table">
          <tr>
            <th class="league-header" colspan="6">MVP</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row-header">
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th class="left-column">Job Title</th>
            <th class="left-column">Number of Logins</th>
          </tr>
          <% @MVPusers.each_with_index do |user, index| %>
            <% if index < 5 %>
              <tr class="tr">
                <td style="padding-top: 20px;"><%= index + 1 %></td>
                <td class="left-column"><%= link_to user do %><%= image_tag user.profile.avatar.url, class: 'sml-avatar-show-img' %><% end %> <%= link_to user do %><%= user.profile.first_name %> <%= user.profile.last_name %><% end %></td>
                <td style="padding-top: 20px;" class="left-column"><%= user.profile.job_title %></td>
                <td style="padding-top: 20px;" class="left-column"><%= user.sign_in_count %></td>
              </tr>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <% if current_user.profile %>
              <tr class="tr user-tr">
                <td style="padding-top: 20px;" ><%= @MVPuser_position + 1 %></td>
                <td class="left-column"><%= link_to user_path(current_user.id) do %><%= image_tag current_user.profile.avatar.url, class: 'sml-avatar-show-img' %><% end %> <%= link_to user_path(current_user.id) do %><%= current_user.profile.first_name %> <%= current_user.profile.last_name %><% end %></td>
                <td style="padding-top: 20px;" class="left-column"><%= current_user.profile.job_title %></td>
                <td style="padding-top: 20px;" class="left-column"><%= current_user.sign_in_count %></td>
              </tr>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Error Log

```
Started GET "/leagues" for xx.xxx.xx.xxx at 2017-03-28 14:23:54 +0000
Cannot render console from xx.xxx.xx.xxx! Allowed networks: xxx.x.x.x, ::1, xxx.x.x.x/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Processing by LeaguesController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY last_sign_in_at DESC
  Profile Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."user_id" IN (9, 3, 8, 7, 6, 5, 2, 4, 1)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY sign_in_count DESC
  Profile Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."user_id" IN (3, 1, 2, 5, 7, 4, 6, 8, 9)
  Rendering leagues/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY last_sign_in_at DESC
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."user_id" IN (9, 3, 8, 7, 6, 5, 2, 4, 1)
  Rendered leagues/index.html.erb within layouts/application (76.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 88ms (ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `avatar' for nil:NilClass):
    21:             <% if index < 5 %>
    22:               <tr class="tr">
    23:                 <td style="padding-top: 20px;"><%= index+1 %></td>
    24:                 <td class="left-column"><%= link_to user do %><%= image_tag user.profile.avatar.url, class: 'sml-avatar-show-img' %><% end %> <%= link_to user do %><%= user.profile.first_name %> <%= user.profile.last_name %><% end %></td>
    25:                 <td style="padding-top: 20px;" class="left-column"><%= user.profile.job_title %></td>
    26:                 <td style="padding-top: 20px;" class="left-column"><%= user.last_sign_in_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %></td>
    27:               </tr>

app/views/leagues/index.html.erb:24:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_leagues_index_html_erb___1987220472087352031_70206048257300'
app/views/leagues/index.html.erb:24:in `block in _app_views_leagues_index_html_erb___1987220472087352031_70206048257300'
app/views/leagues/index.html.erb:20:in `each_with_index'
app/views/leagues/index.html.erb:20:in `_app_views_leagues_index_html_erb___1987220472087352031_70206048257300'
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (7.2ms)
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.7ms)
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@saasapp/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (38.7ms)
```

If you'd like to see any other files, let me know in the comments. Would appreciate any help/advice with this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please post your error message (the log).

Comment: @HolgerFrohloff Oops, just added the log

Comment: On SO we don't put "SOLVED" in questions. Instead, we select the answer that provided the solution to mark it. Also, salutations, valedictions and signatures are not wanted so the last line should be removed. Remember, SO isn't a discussion list, it's a reference book more like an encyclopedia or cookbook, where conciseness and clarity is more important. Your question was the opening question to a page providing a solution to that problem for other people searching for similar solutions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see your view file, but I'm assuming you're calling .avatar on each user or on their profile?

If you change user.avatar or user.profile.avatar to:

```
user.avatar if user.avatar
```

or

```
user.profile.avatar if user.profile && user.profile.avatar
```

then you should clear your error and just receive a blank area where their avatar should be.

EDIT: After looking at the view file, one of these two lines:

```
<%= image_tag user.profile.avatar.url, class: 'sml-avatar-show-img' %>

<%= image_tag current_user.profile.avatar.url, class: 'sml-avatar-show-img' %>
```

Is apparently throwing the error. Change them to:

```
<%= (image_tag user.profile.avatar.url, class: 'sml-avatar-show-img') if user.profile && user.profile.avatar %>

<%= (image_tag current_user.profile.avatar.url, class: 'sml-avatar-show-img') if current_user && current_user.profile && current_user.profile.avatar %>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark, will give it a go now although I have another index.html.erb file showing a list of all users (not the league table page) which doesn't have the 'if user.avatar' and that page works fine. I've also tried removing the avatar line completely and the following error I get is about the first_name so I think it's an issue with the Model/Controller?

Comment: The problem will persist. You need to make sure the record/object you are calling the method on is actually present. That's what Mark is trying to explain here. :)

Comment: Try changing the two lines in my edit and it should work - sorry that's all I can think of

Comment: @Mark I've removed a load of the HTML and just left the avatar lines and it is now appearing. Thank you so much for your help. This has been driving me crazy for a while. Will get round to adding the same for the other objects.

Comment: Happy to help! Sometimes it's counter intuitive but 95% of the time the error message will point out what's going wrong or point you in the right direction (avatar in this case)

Answer (score 0):

You received the common `for nil:NilClass` error. You have a list in your index view, where you try to display the record's attributes.
You access these attributes by calling their getter method on the record. The only problem here is, that your record value is `nil`. There is no record.

Specifically: you used `user.profile.avatar` The `user`record is there, but when you call `.profile` on this `user`, you receive `nil`.
You can make sure to check whether the record is available before calling the method on it. An idea on how to do it is given in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43072430/299781)

> Can you see any issue with my controller/model which might explain why these records aren't available?

Your `LeaguesController` loads the `User` records. But you access your `users`'s profiles in your view. You need to make sure, that your `User`s have an associated `profile` before accessing them.

Comment: Thanks Holger, please see my reply to Mark. Can you see any issue with my controller/model which might explain why these records aren't available?